# Calculate Months in Population

Tags: powerpivot, webi

I need to make an output table that lists clients in the first column,  followed by entry date and exit date, followed by columns with the months of the year as column headers. Desired output is a mark (X) in each month column for each month the client was a member of the population.

Something that would look like a Gantt Chart, but instead of tracking Project Timelines, would track which months in a year a person was a member of a population.

Tools available to me are WeBI, Excel/PowerPivot, maybe Tableau. I am going round in circles picking the appropriate tool because it will be used to fill out a form for a grant. I'm looking at some gantt chart templates, which may work, but i fear the funder is looking for an X in a particular column.

I know it's a very general question. I'd love some feed back and direction.  Thanks!

Comment: This can be done in Excel Power Pivot, or Power BI (the same engine, different UI). To do that, you will need to build your data model correctly (a properly structured star schema), and then use DAX to write calculations (which are trivial in this case). If you decide to pursue this road, I'd recommend to try it and then post more specific questions if you run into obstacles.

Comment: I figured it could be done pretty easily in PowerBI/Pivot. The calculations are definitely easy and the data model would be very simple.  My data would either be client ID number, location id, entry date and exit date on one table or it comes raw in one table for clients, one for entries, one for exits. one for location. I have a star schema data model set up  for those separate tables, already. Those are the core elements of my work, any day of the week.
I'm struggling with getting to the visualization/data table output. The final output actually goes to the funder as an Excel workbook.

Comment: These could be acheive using WebI crosstable with customer X dates, and then a formula to compute the 'X' for the adequate months. If you share a sample (or an example) of your data I can give it a try